# Консоль IPython не выдает результат

Tags: консоль, if, ipython

Использую конструкцию if-else. При выполнении первого условия программа выдает нужный текст, при выполнении другого условия программа просто выполняется без информации в консоли

```
from __future__ import print_function
import io
  
word = u'заявление'
with io.open('filepath', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for line in file:
        if word in line:
            x = "заявление"
            if x == word:
                print("Категория: Заявление")
            else
                print('Категория не определена')
```

Comment: `else:` а не `else`

Answer (score 0):

У вас условие всегда выполняется, ведь и x и word равны "заявление". Else никогда не выполнится.
Скорее всего вы хотели написать другое чуть выше:

```
for word in line: # for, а не if
```

Comment: в этом случае теперь всегда выполняется else

Comment: А в файле точно есть "заявление" именно с маленькой буквы?

Comment: да, с маленькой

Comment: @IMPYTHONNOOB Покажите всё-таки пример - несколько строк из вашего файла, желательно где есть "заявление"

Comment: могу я лично с вами связаться?

Comment: @IMPYTHONNOOB Можете написать мне на crazyelf@mail.ru